# Organizar paginação

Tags: php, mysql

Eu gostaria que em cada página ficasse os resultados de todos os jogos do dia "x".
Exemplo: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nessa página apenas os jogos do dia 06 de junho de 2017, porém está aparecendo todos os jogos da tabela.
OBS*: Eu estou organizando as datas pro formato dia/mes/ano na hora da exibição.

Eu estou usando esse código, porém não está organizando.
As datas estão armazenados assim na coluna: ano/mês/dia

```
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM resultados ORDER BY rodada DESC LIMIT $inicio, $per_pagina");
$query->execute();
```

Comment: Qual é o nome da coluna do dia? seria o "rodada", ela contem somente data ou hora também?

Comment: sim, é a coluna rodada ela contem só a data no formato ano/mes/dia